# Benefits of Vipassana Meditation

Tags: vipassana, meditation-effects

I've decided to do I'm thinking if meditation would help me to concentrate my study(academic). Also would it help me to feel Buddha and Dhamma? Will my memory sharp? Currently I feel little bit depressed so would this be cured if I'll attend ten days of Vipassana meditation?

Comment: See also [Want a new tag, e.g. for office work and academic work?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2072/254)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've decided to do I'm thinking if meditation would help me to
>   concentrate my study(academic).

Vipassana meditation will help in studies. Since vipassana meditation focuses on removing craving, anger and illusion, you will notice your mind clear of when you study.

> Also would it help me to feel Buddha and Dhamma?

Just before Buddha reached parinibbhäna, he stated, at his absence Dhamma would be our teacher. Dhamma was Buddhas teacher too. Buddha also has said, the person who sees dhamma sees him.

> Will my memory sharp?

Even with a clear mind, you have to follow memory basics to remember.

1. To improve short term memory: **Repeat to remember**
2. To improve long term memory: **Remember to repeat**

*This is from the book Brain Rules*. It's a well researched and accepted book so grab a copy if you can. By Melina.

> Currently I feel little bit depressed so would this be cured if I'll
>   attend ten days of Vipassana meditation?

Unlikely. You need a slightly longer commitment. Start with a three month plan with an excellent diet, good sleep, ample exercise. Visit a doctor about this if you haven't. Use vipassana meditation for the purpose it was intended for, not depression. Read the book "Spark" by Ratey, if you feel you can do something additional to what a doctor asks you, to get over depression.

Comment: I had to psychiatrist but it couldn't help me. He had doubt I'm lying about my problems. Anyway this way is always better than psychiatrist. Thank you. I'll refer books you suggested. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever Buddha taught was aimed at attaining nirvana. Vipassana meditation is to achieve nirvana. If you go through this journey, you can pick up something you want on the way. If you do so, there will be the delay and even you may lose bearing. What you mention are just like the stations you have to pass on the journey by train. If you are waiting one by one you will get it but slowly and not all at the same time. If you target at nirvana, you will get these all in a short time definitely.